# A semilinear heat equation with concave-convex nonlinearity

Tags: partial-differential-equations

hi   while reading article of T. CAZENAVE – F. DICKSTEIN – M. ESCOBED :A semilinear heat equation
with concave-convex nonlinearity ,there issomepoints which are not  not clear for me:

1. is this equation seminear or non linear :
   [image]

because some times he says that is semilinear and sometimes nonlinear?

2. he supposes that there is a function $u_{\alpha}$ which verify $(1.1)$ with initial data $u_{\alpha}(0)$ converging to $u_{0}$ and then he says that we deduce $u_{\alpha}$ converge to u so how can one prove that ? i know that by comparaison principle we have only : $u_{\alpha}\le u$
   thanks